# scapy's contrib is missing after installing scapy on both windows and fedora

Tags: python, scapy

I have installed scapy both on my windows 7 and my fedora machines. However, the contrib package does not get installed (or at least, it does not appear under my site-packages/scapy package.
How can I get it to install?

Comment: What version of Scapy did you install?

Comment: I installed Scapy version 2.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the zip file provided at http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/ I don't see the contrib folder. For some reason it is not bundled into the zip.

You should be able to download the source of Scapy 2.2.0 directly and install that using setup.py, which does has the contrib folder.

You'll need mercurial to clone the code from BitBucket, and update to the v2.2.0 release that is tagged with the update command.

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy
cd scapy
hg update -r v2.2.0
```

In addition, you need to add the contrib package to the packages array in setup.py as follows:

```
packages=['scapy','scapy/arch', 'scapy/arch/windows', 
'scapy/layers','scapy/asn1','scapy/tools','scapy/modules', 'scapy/crypto', 
'scapy/contrib' ]
```

Once there you should be able to install using `python setup.py install` and the `contrib` module should be present.

Comment: Thanks. I did need to modify setup.py to include the contrib package as follows:

    packages=['scapy','scapy/arch', 'scapy/arch/windows', 'scapy/layers','scapy/asn1','scapy/tools','scapy/modules', 'scapy/crypto', 'scapy/contrib' ]